# Variables not read correctly in custom Rust kernel

Tags: rust, kernel, x86-64, bootloader, osdev

I have a custom bootloader, that boots into a custom kernel written in Rust. The bootloader elevates from real to protected mode, then from protected to extended. Then, it calls the `_start()` function in my kernel from a file `entry.asm` with the following code:

```
[bits 64]
[extern _start]

kstart:
    call _start
    jmp $
```

The kernel itself consists only of the following code:

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    let vga_buffer = 0xb8000 as *mut u8;

    let mut Hello = b"Hello World!";
    for (i, &byte) in Hello.iter().enumerate() {
        unsafe {
            *vga_buffer.offset(i as isize * 2) = byte;
            *vga_buffer.offset(i as isize * 2 + 1) = 0x42;
        }
    }

    loop {}
}
```

This is compiled with a custom target, specified in the following JSON file (the same as the one used in [the tutorial I have been trying to follow](https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/#target-specification)):

```json
{
    "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
    "arch": "x86_64",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

And using the `build-std` features of nightly Cargo, as defined in the `config.toml` file:

```ini
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]
build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]

[build]
target = "x86_64-axolotlos.json"
```

Then, after building the kernel code, I link the resulting object file (renamed kernel.elf) to the one produced from compiling `entry.asm` with the -felf64 flag of NASM (entry.elf) with `ld` using the following script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
INPUT("entry.elf", "kernel.elf")
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x8200;

    .text . : SUBALIGN(0) {
        entry.elf(.text)
        kernel.elf(.text)
    }

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.comment)
        *(.eh_frame)
    }
}
```

I then append the resulting binary file to the one compiled from the bootloader itself using `cat`, and execute that with QEMU.

The problem is that make the string `"Hello world!"` appear on the screen. I can see that the background colour has been changed, and if I specify some character directly like `'a'` or `'H'`, it is printed with the correct foreground colour too, so the kernel and the VGA are being correctly accessed. But from the moment I define a string in the code, although it is being iterated on, the bytes are all null or same garbage value, as if it was reading the length of the string somewhere else than where it is located. Worse, if I define variables as static, it straight up ignores them, even though I can find them in the final image file with `xxd`. My best guess is that this problem comes from the linking stage, but I don't know where.

Sorry for the long question, I tried to provide full context for the problem. I can give more code if necessary; apart from the `Cargo.toml` and the bootloader itself, these are all the files that I use to build and link the bootloader and the kernel.

---

Following a suggestion by @MichaelPetch, here is the output of `objdump -x` on `entry.elf`:

```
kernel/entry.elf:     file format elf64-x86-64
kernel/entry.elf
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000000000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000007  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000001c0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 entry.asm
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l       .text  0000000000000000 kstart
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _start


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000001 R_X86_64_PC32     _start-0x0000000000000004
```

And `kernel.elf`:

```
kernel/kernel.elf:     file format elf64-x86-64
kernel/kernel.elf
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000201410

Program Header:
    PHDR off    0x0000000000000040 vaddr 0x0000000000200040 paddr 0x0000000000200040 align 2**3
         filesz 0x0000000000000150 memsz 0x0000000000000150 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000200000 paddr 0x0000000000200000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000000000003f7 memsz 0x00000000000003f7 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000400 vaddr 0x0000000000201400 paddr 0x0000000000201400 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000000000009d2 memsz 0x00000000000009d2 flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000dd8 vaddr 0x0000000000202dd8 paddr 0x0000000000202dd8 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000000000000a8 memsz 0x00000000000000a8 flags rw-
   RELRO off    0x0000000000000dd8 vaddr 0x0000000000202dd8 paddr 0x0000000000202dd8 align 2**0
         filesz 0x00000000000000a8 memsz 0x0000000000000228 flags r--
   STACK off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**0
         filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000000 flags rw-

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .rodata       00000267  0000000000200190  0000000000200190  00000190  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .text         000009d2  0000000000201400  0000000000201400  00000400  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .data.rel.ro  000000a8  0000000000202dd8  0000000000202dd8  00000dd8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  3 .debug_abbrev 00003803  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000e80  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
  4 .debug_info   0008c345  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00004683  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
  5 .debug_aranges 0000de40  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000909c8  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
  6 .debug_ranges 0002aa80  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0009e808  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
  7 .debug_str    00084452  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000c9288  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
  8 .debug_pubnames 00030701  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0014d6da  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
  9 .debug_pubtypes 00029af2  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0017dddb  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
 10 .comment      00000048  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  001a78cd  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 11 .debug_frame  0001cd30  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  001a7918  2**3
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
 12 .debug_line   0003e0f6  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  001c4648  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
 13 .debug_loc    00002075  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0020273e  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING, OCTETS
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 1sttrwc8gvr9yq3p
00000000002001b0 l     O .rodata    0000000000000021 str.0
00000000002001e0 l     O .rodata    000000000000001c str.1
0000000000201400 l     F .text  0000000000000007 .hidden rust_begin_unwind
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.03
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.04
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.00
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.02
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.05
0000000000201810 l     F .text  0000000000000007 .hidden _ZN4core3ptr88drop_in_place$LT$core..panic..panic_info..PanicInfo..internal_constructor..NoPayload$GT$17h0af650329bb5f184E
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.01
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.06
0000000000201850 l     F .text  0000000000000023 .hidden _ZN4core3ptr7mut_ptr31_$LT$impl$u20$$BP$mut$u20$T$GT$7is_null12runtime_impl17ha09cfa347178a18bE
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.07
0000000000200200 l     O .rodata    000000000000001c str.0
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.08
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.09
0000000000201a10 l     F .text  000000000000000b .hidden _ZN4core5panic8location8Location6caller17h77215c5033637d85E
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.10
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.11
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.12
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.13
0000000000201ae0 l     F .text  0000000000000071 _ZN4core5panic10panic_info9PanicInfo20internal_constructor17hcb1421f837569d0bE
0000000000201c20 l     F .text  0000000000000068 _ZN4core9panicking18panic_nounwind_fmt7runtime17hf6cbace78c043c4aE
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.14
0000000000201d30 l     F .text  00000000000000a2 .hidden _ZN4core3fmt9Arguments9new_const17h4c87c6b90959701aE
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 core.261b61bde2c4f326-cgu.15
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 compiler_builtins.2f4846e6fe9e6975-cgu.0
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 compiler_builtins.2f4846e6fe9e6975-cgu.1
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 compiler_builtins.2f4846e6fe9e6975-cgu.2
0000000000201410 g     F .text  00000000000001b3 _start
0000000000201a20 g     F .text  0000000000000018 _ZN4core5slice29_$LT$impl$u20$$u5b$T$u5d$$GT$4iter17he3894612517fb75fE
00000000002015d0 g     F .text  0000000000000023 _ZN4core4iter6traits8iterator8Iterator9enumerate17h9b71327f5489503aE
00000000002019f0 g     F .text  000000000000001a _ZN63_$LT$I$u20$as$u20$core..iter..traits..collect..IntoIterator$GT$9into_iter17hc90f197ca657d188E
0000000000201900 g     F .text  00000000000000e2 _ZN110_$LT$core..iter..adapters..enumerate..Enumerate$LT$I$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..iter..traits..iterator..Iterator$GT$4next17h6a9a968253e0e027E
0000000000201c90 g     F .text  0000000000000047 _ZN4core9panicking5panic17h40f0a462f96653d0E
00000000002017a0 g     F .text  0000000000000044 _ZN75_$LT$core..option..Option$LT$T$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..ops..try_trait..Try$GT$6branch17he01135bd123273fbE
00000000002017f0 g     F .text  000000000000001c _ZN84_$LT$core..option..Option$LT$T$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..ops..try_trait..FromResidual$GT$13from_residual17h55abe1489ca282a4E
00000000002018d0 g     F .text  0000000000000024 _ZN4core4iter8adapters9enumerate18Enumerate$LT$I$GT$3new17hc893f5ede3c189ccE
0000000000201690 g     F .text  000000000000010a _ZN91_$LT$core..slice..iter..Iter$LT$T$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..iter..traits..iterator..Iterator$GT$4next17hd2b3f3c84da2cbdfE
0000000000201600 g     F .text  0000000000000082 _ZN4core5slice4iter13Iter$LT$T$GT$3new17hefc8df1601795247E
0000000000201a40 g     F .text  0000000000000059 _ZN4core3ptr8non_null16NonNull$LT$T$GT$13new_unchecked17hab63170547322e98E
0000000000201aa0 g     F .text  000000000000002d _ZN78_$LT$core..ptr..non_null..NonNull$LT$T$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..cmp..PartialEq$GT$2eq17h0cf05d91f4278f6eE
0000000000201b60 g     F .text  0000000000000055 _ZN4core9panicking9panic_fmt17hd97d846be2b0a028E
0000000000201ce0 g     F .text  0000000000000044 _ZN4core9panicking14panic_nounwind17h940e63cf2d8658fdE
0000000000201820 g     F .text  0000000000000022 _ZN4core3ptr7mut_ptr31_$LT$impl$u20$$BP$mut$u20$T$GT$7is_null17h6d1e66821aef48eaE
0000000000201880 g     F .text  000000000000004d _ZN4core3any6TypeId2of17hecd010ab7407e19aE
0000000000201bc0 g     F .text  0000000000000057 _ZN4core9panicking18panic_nounwind_fmt17hee2a658420459466E
0000000000201ad0 g     F .text  000000000000000c _ZN36_$LT$T$u20$as$u20$core..any..Any$GT$7type_id17h1616718efb43f34dE
```

Comment: If I had to guess, the problem is likely before your kernel is started. Are you reading enough sectors in memory to cover the entire size of the binary? Have you set all the segment registers correctly?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think I am reading enough sectors, I use `wc -c` and divide the result by 512 to get the sector count, but there might be better ways (especially since I have to build, check the required number of sectors, then re-build, but that was something I was leaving for later to change). As for the segment registers, I don't set them in any particular way before calling the kernel, is there something I'm missing there?

Comment: If you are in long mode then the segment selectors are probably okay. Not reading enough sectors is a common problem. Number of 512 sectors to read would be better described as (sizeofbinary+511)/512 which would have the effect of rounding up to the nearest 512. Have you verified that the kernel on disk was properly loaded into memory?

Comment: I think it is, since I can find the variables defined in the kernel code in the final image file produced by concatenating the bootloader and kernel binaries. However, I found that if I tried printing a string using a pointer to its address in the `xxd` dump, it worked as expected by adding the bootloader offset of 0x7c00. But my kernel is supposed to be loaded at 0x8200, and I expected the linker script to offset the addresses correctly...

Comment: Looking at your linker script you seem to have built ELF executables and linked those together? (I don't know how you built the `ELF` files). But you really should be using the linker script to link `.o` (OBJECT) files. This isn't an [mcve] so I can only guess since I don't know how you make anything and I don't know what your bootloader looks like. etc.

Comment: Sorry, you are right; I build the kernel with `cargo +nightly build`, all else being defined in the `config.toml` and the target JSON file. I compile the entry file with `nasm -felf64 o entry.elf entry.asm`, and then link the kernel executable and the entry file ELF with the linker script I provided. Since the bootloader is compiled separately and consists of several folders with a number of files inside, I didn't want to further complicate the question by talking about it.

Comment: However, I didn't know that I should be linking the object files instead of ELF, so I'll be searching information on that next, thank you for your answers!

Comment: I'm not an expert Rust developer. I am curious. When you build `kernel.elf` is there a custome linker script being used (some people call it `link.ld` as an example). One thing that might be useful is the output from the command `objdump -x kernel.elf` and `objdump -x entry.elf`. I have a hunch that the virtual memory address in those ELF files isn't correct for one or both of them.

Comment: This is unlikely the problem, but you need to use `write_voltaile()`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch When I call Cargo to build the kernel, all the necessary flags for the compilation are present in the `config.toml`, telling it to rebuild the core features, compiler builtins and memory functions for a custom target defined in the JSON file I provided. It doesn't do anything more than that, and produces the `kernel.elf` which I then link with `entry.elf` with the script.

Comment: I have ran the two `objdump` commands, but I'm not sure what I should be looking at; the start address? It is 0x0 for `entry.elf` and 0x201550 for `kernel.elf`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks, I didn't know, why is that?

Comment: So the compiler doesn't optimize the write away.

Comment: Can you add the output of both `objdump` commands I gave to your question. I want to see it all.

Comment: Done, I have updated the question with the full output of both commands.

Comment: When you use GDB to attach to QEMU as a remote, you should be able to verify memory contents to check that your sectors were indeed loaded.  (You could put some interesting bit-patterns in them, like some `0xcccccccc` variables in each page, which probably won't appear randomly.  Or `0x11111111` in one page, `0x22222222` in another, etc.)  You can of could also single-step your code to see exactly what goes wrong.  If you haven't previously used a debugger for asm, now is the time to start; it's an essential tool. Bochs has a built-in debugger that knows about x86 segmentation and paging, BTW.

Comment: Your generated kernel code seems to expect to be running above the 2MiB mark and as well unless your bootloader has an ELF loader and can do memory location fixups this isn't going to work. It appears like you are using a tutorial that expects a bootloader that can load an ELF file and fixup memory references. I'm guessing your bootloader doesn't do any of that?

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't know about attaching GDB to QEMU, I will look into that, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelPetch I see! No, my bootloader just starts at 0x7c00, reads some sectors from disk, then elevates to 32 and 64 bits (setting up thinks like the GDT and paging along the way) and then calls the kernel at 0x8200, so well under 2MiB. In fact, the tutorial I was following for the kernel (https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/) uses its own bootloader (https://github.com/rust-osdev/bootloader), which from what I can see does indeed load the kernel ELF.